# Importing RAW Image from NSItemProvider

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using `itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: "public.image")` for fetching images from gallery but it throws `Cannot load representation of type public.image` error. Does anyone know how to fix and fetch the RAW images from gallery?

EDIT:

on iOS 16 and below I have tried with these UTTypes already [.png, .jpeg, .image, .rawImage, .pdf] and many more but it's always same error.

I was also seeing many reported this on Apple's developer forum.

But apparently this issue is finally fixed on iOS 17. I was able to get the image's local URL with my latest iOS 17 beta installed device. So I'm dropping this one if anyone encountered same issues.